# Remove value from array?

Tags: c++-cli

How can I take out one line of this array

```
  array< array< int^ >^ >^ sample = gcnew array< array< int^ >^ >{
        gcnew array<int>{0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        gcnew array<int>{1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
        gcnew array<int>{2, 2, 2, 2, 2},
    };
```

So it would be :-

```
  array< array< int^ >^ >^ sample = gcnew array< array< int^ >^ >{
        gcnew array<int>{0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        gcnew array<int>{2, 2, 2, 2, 2},
    };
```

Rajesh.

Answer (score 1):

While you can use `Array::Resize` to resize your array and use the shift method bachchan mentions, you generally don't add or remove items from a C++/CLI array.

If you need add or remove items dynamically from a collection, look into using the `System::Collections::Generic::List<T>` type (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx)).

Depending on what you're doing with the collection, you can use even more sophisticated structures, e.g. `HashSet<T>` or `Dictionary<K, V>`.

Answer (score 0):

for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ ) 
{
  if ( a[i] == target )
    break;
}

while ( ++i < n )
  a[i - 1] = a[i];
 --n;

The actual process doesn't include a delete step, it's just the shift step: